# Universal Studios on Black Friday or Saturday?

Tags: usa, thanksgiving, universal-studios

The family & I are in LA for the Thanksgiving weekend and are trying to figure out whether to visit Universal on Black Friday or Saturday.

Any idea whether the choice of days will make a difference? In the case of this weekend, one day is rainy and one isn't, is that likely to make more difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny you should ask; I've checked with my 'source' who lives in LA, works for NBCUniversal, and has a season's pass to Universal Studios.

In her view, rain means fewer Californians will go, and 90% of the time the "rain" is light and intermittent.

This week, there probably won't be a huge difference between Black Friday and Saturday, although Saturday might be preferable because it's supposed to be cooler.

Above all: have a great time.

Comment: @pnuts not really; it rains so infrequently, and it's so light when it does, that it's not much of a deterrence. It's more likely that the real start of the Christmas shopping will mean it's less crowded on both days.